# UIB tabs - set second tabs is active

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Its is uib bootstrap plugin. Default active the first tab.
I need to set the  second tab is default active. Kindly help me as soon as possible.

```
  <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
        angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function($scope, $window) {

        });
        </script>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
            <uib-tabset active="active">
                <uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title">Static First</uib-tab>
                <uib-tab index="1" heading="Static title1">Static Second</uib-tab>
                <uib-tab index="2" heading="Static title2" active="true">Static Third</uib-tab>
            </uib-tabset>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like:

```
<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl" ng-init="indextab = 1">
    <uib-tabset active="indextab">
        <uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title">Static First</uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="1" heading="Static title1">Static Second</uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="2" heading="Static title2" active="true">Static Third</uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

does what you need.

**Updated** [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wpBJSu6Z9wlVWqzUxGiE?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, When i set indextab = 1 statically it works, but when i pass index value dynamically doesn't works. indextab sets only  to 0 , not 1 or 2

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding it correctly but in this other plunker the index is set dynamically: http://plnkr.co/edit/HFywA5heqlxhTEKpxuBu?p=preview

Comment: thanks for reply .. now its working ... when i pass tab value through url the value is in string format , after i convert it to int ( using parseInt ) it works...